# Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'?

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, adb

I am running Windos 7 and Eclipse 3.5 and I don't know why I keep getting this error. When I try run the program it gives me:

```
[2010-02-13 23:09:41 - HelloAndroid]The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2010-02-13 23:09:41 - HelloAndroid]You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2010-02-13 23:09:41 - HelloAndroid]Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\AndroidSDK\tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

I even tried runing Eclipse and adb.exe as admin. What is going on? How can I fix this and start making Android apps?

Comment: I am running Win7 and it is working fine here - hence not a win7 problem but rather a configuration problem with your system.  

Did you check that the add.exe is located at C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\AndroidSDK\tools\adb.exe  ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes i had the same problem after i had did the update,

however, i have just fixed it :)
TO FIX THE PROMBLEM:

in folder: \android-sdk-windows\
go to folder \platform-tools ;  copy the files
and paste in to folder  \tool

Restart the Eclipse

Answer (score 25):

turned off COMODO Defense+ module and all worked....

Comment: Indeed it was COMODO's fault in my case

Comment: omg, after more then half a day re-installing, testing etc ... damn COMODO and thanks Cool Khan!!

Comment: it was the behavior blocker in my case that did evil, disabling it when starting Eclipse works

Comment: Add the adb.exe to trusted files. It will work like a charm. No need to turn off comodo.

Answer (score 20):

If you have **comodo internet security** installed, you dont have to shut this feature down:

1. run comodo settings
2. defense+
3. list active processes
4. add adb.exe to trusted processes
5. restart server: run "adb kill-server" "adb start-server"

**EDIT**: For user of **Comodo 6.x**

1. Open Comodo
2. Click Tasks Icon at right top
3. Click Advanced Tasks
4. Click Open Advanced Settings
5. Select Security Settings --> File Rating --> Trusted files from
    left panel
6. Click on the upward arrow icon at the bottom
7. Click Add --> add the adb.exe

there you go :) Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for checking Comodo, dammit!  What's annoying is that i'd already exited Comodo from the tooltray, so had foolishly assumed it couldnt be affecting me.  Restarted, added to the defense+ list and we're good.

Answer (score 3):

I messed with all the solutions provided above, but I found another one-

**Try launching eclipse with administrator privileges**

> RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR

hope it'll do the job.

Comment: I tried pretty much everything else I could find on the subject of adb.exe hanging/freezing, nothing else worked. Thanks. Hope it keeps working!

Answer (score 2):

After installing 2.3 SDK I got adb inside D:\AndroidSetup\android-sdk-
windows\platform-tools directory. I had set this path in environment
variable and my problem is solved.

Comment: There's a file in /tools called "adb_has_moved.txt" that explains this issue and says you need to update the PATH vars to include /platform-tools. Ram's right.

Answer (score 2):

Two options to solve this problem on windows:

**Option 1:**

1. Close the eclipse, if it is running.
2. Run the command prompt.
3. Go to the tools location of the android sdk.
4. run 'adb kill-server'
5. then run 'adb start-server'.
6. start the eclipse.

**Option 2:**

1. Open the task manager.
2. kill the adb process.
3. start the eclipse.

Problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

What it work for me and this was because I move from one eclipse to another is to re install SDK and then re install ADT again, remove completly from eclipse ADT and re install.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a58725e7e22eb200), you may need to kill an exisiting `abd` process, or unblock the 5037 port (remnants of previous `adb` start attempts).

> Try closing Eclipse, issuing a 
>   '`C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\AndroidSDK\tools kill-server`' command from terminal and retrying.
>   If that still doesn't work, you could try opening Activity Monitor to see if there are any existing adb processes running, and kill them.
>
> Hi, it's OK now, I'saw with the `nestat - a` command line that theer was several processus on the 5037 port. The port wich serves for the emulator.
>   Thanks

Comment: Well I tried to kill and start the server. So I guess the problem is the blocked 5037 port. So how do I unblock it? (I am running Windows 7 Pro)

Comment: @Mohit: since `netstat -o` does include the process id (PID) in its output, you could try and kill any process linked to that port.

Comment: Weird, port 5037 is not listed. The closest thing to it would be the 5040 port.

Comment: @Mohit: depending on your configuration, the port number might be different. A tool like a Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can show you if the `PID` associated with that port number is a `abd` one.

Comment: `netstat` will not list directly `abd`. Did you mean your Process Explorer does not display any `abd` process?

Answer (score 0):

force to start sdk manager several times (try directly from the file explorer). when you could do that comodo may send a mesage. allow the issue. then start again the sdk manager and update.
update eclipse then.