# Failed to upload myapp.apk

Tags: android

All of a sudden I couldn't upload my apk on my device while debugging/running it from eclipse, this is the error:

```
[2010-07-11 12:30:04 - myapp] Failed to upload myapp.apk on device '181D09BAD5D96180'
[2010-07-11 12:30:04 - myapp] java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection!
[2010-07-11 12:30:04 - myapp] Launch canceled!
```

i tried in the adb kill-server and start-server also tried to reboot/shut down my comp and/or my phone but nothing helps.

I'm using adk 1.5.

any idea?

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse, and don't forget to click on your device when it shows up in the devices tab.

Comment: is the device getting listed when you do a 'adb devices' ?

Comment: Something wierd.. ive tried to go to an earlier version of my apk and it worked normal.. i cant think about something ive done that managed to get me into this problem.

if i go back to that apl(the one which doesnt work) doesnt matter what i do.. still there that prob occours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOException everytime I try to upload anything to android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269579/ioexception-everytime-i-try-to-upload-anything-to-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the prob folks.
i have channged some of my package which contain an AIDL file, and eclipse does some auto-gen code, i had to delete it and re-compile.

ofcourse the error i got wasnt appropriate, but now it works.

thank you all anyway for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think eclipse only does a reinstall, maybe you should uninstall your app from the device (with "adb uninstall") or from the applications list on the device itself. Maybe that helps.

Another suggestion would be to disable your antivirus software (if any).

Answer (score 0):

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269579/ioexception-everytime-i-try-to-upload-anything-to-android-emulator) Raphael mentions issues with the `Drawable` folder. Did you add any new drawable to the new version?

Also check there is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5355) created related with your problem.