# Eclipse/adb error message in Vista "Failed to parse the output of adb version"

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I am trying to learn Android development, so I downloaded Eclipse Galileo and the Android SDK. However, whenever I start Eclipse, I get the error message "Failed to parse the output of adb version." In the Console/DDMS pane, the debug output reads:

[2010-06-07 20:15:13 - ddms]Failed to reopen debug port for Selected Client to: 8700
[2010-06-07 20:15:13 - ddms]Address family not supported by protocol family: bind
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: bind
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.reopenDebugSelectedPort(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(Unknown Source)

[2010-06-07 20:15:17 - adb]Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'

I am running Eclipse Galileo, have the most recent Android SDK downloaded, and am running Windows Vista 32-bit SP2. I am sure that the Android SDK path is correct and that all the files are there.

I would appreciate any assistance anyone could provide.

P.S.--If anyone could direct me to any useful Android development resources, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I did address the "[Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260118/failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version)".

But when happening in conjunction with "Failed to reopen debug port for Selected Client to", you might need to:

- check your "`C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`" and make sure it contains "`127.0.0.1       localhost`" (see [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg28062.html))
- or check the ACL of that same file ([this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg31116.html))

Note: the Android-developer blog has actually [mentioned Stack Overflow](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html) as a good resource for Android questions;)

Comment: That solved the error with the debug ports, thank you very much. ADB issue still persists though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a58725e7e22eb200) will help you.

Try changing the port under:
"Window->Preferences->Android->DDMS->ADB debugger base port" to something else.

Comment: Any specific suggestions (5038, 5700, XXXX, etc.) on a port to change it to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread will help you.

Try changing the port under: "Window->Preferences->Android->DDMS->ADB debugger base port" to something else.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a problem with Eclipse on startup stating that adb could not be started. It had worked before. So after searching the internet I found that there was a problem with the latest Java jdk. So I downloaded the latest and greatest version 6 and voila it worked! Not sure if this will help you with your problem.