# Failed to parse output of 'adb version'?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am using windows 7, Eclipse Indigo and ADT. I wasted a day because of this issue. Before getting this issue, I performed an updation in SDKManager. I tried following steps, but all ended with disappointment.

1. Run Eclipse and adb as admin
2. Set the environment variable to tools and platform-tool folder
3. start and kill adb several times as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094080
4. Copied files from platform-tools to tool https://stackoverflow.com/a/4398830/1023223
5. Comodo is my antivirus softwere. So I tried this one too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8988993/1023223 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715755
6. Downloaded new SDK.

Is there any other solution to solve this issue??[image]

Comment: If you do `adb version` manually via commandline for the adb tool used by eclipse (Window > Preferences > SDK Path), is there output that looks like `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31`? Also: Did you  update the eclipse plugin? (Help > Check for Updates)

Comment: @zapl yea.. it shows Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31..yes, I updated

Comment: @zapl Format my system is the final way to solve??

Comment: Maybe there is something else than Comodo causing this. Some other firewall / anti virus / security thing that is able to block software. The problem seems to be something like that - it should find `adb` but it does not get any result from executing it programmatically. The error would IMO be different if it would not find it at all. You could try it programatically yourself and see if that works http://pastebin.com/ij9VK9r8 - You could also try to disable or uninstall all security related software that could cause that and and you can finally remove / uninstall every adb version / eclipse

Comment: Was stuck with this for ages. Exact same symptoms - thanks for that little example program @zapl, it was useful - it turns out that even exiting Comodo leaves their 'Defense+' service running somehow, so although i could run adb.exe from java, it was blocking the output. Interesting huh