# The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.You must restart adb and Eclipse.Please ensure that adb is correctly located

Tags: android, eclipse, environment-variables, adb

I know this question is asked multiple time and there are some alternative answer also.So please don't close with some other link because i have added that link below.

```
[2014-01-23 16:19:44 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
[2014-01-23 16:19:44 - adb] * failed to start daemon *
....
....
[2014-01-23 14:48:10 - My App] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-01-23 14:48:10 - My App] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-01-23 14:48:10 - My App] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'E:\Chintan Khetiya\Android KIT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Some of the grate Answer

- [Kill from Task Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035456/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occurred) - In this case i am not able to delete my process. When i just delete it will automatically create new.(showing me more the one adb in task manger)

[image]

- [Kill from ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-sever-error-has-occured) - This works me some times but I have to do this process at least two or three times. So at least i have to restart my eclipse two or three times minimum and its very time consuming.

[image]

- [Copy `/Platform-Tool` to `/Tool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260118/failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version)- I don't know but i have tried this one also.

Finally I am looking for some solution in which i can solve this issue because i am facing this issue at least four times in a day so i am irritate now to restart again and again. I am wasting my 1 hours for this issue in a day.

***Anyone have some permanent solution for my issue.?***

I don't know why this error showing me in console.

**System Requirements:**

- Operating System - Windows - 7
- Processor - Core 2 Duo
- RAM - 4 GB
- Android SDK - Up to - 4.4.2 - 19 API level (All most latest)

Environment Path:

```
E:\Chintan Khetiya\Android KIT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platform-tools;
E:\Chintan Khetiya\Android KIT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools
```

Thank you.

Comment: Having gone thru all answers in this Question and tried everything it transpired that my phone ( running on a Sony Xperia) had disconnected the debugger and caused the problem.  I am posting this in case it is of use to anybody in future.  THe phone was no longer showing in the list of Devices for running the apk.  Also running  "adb devices" from the command prompt showed no devices

Answer (score 13):

I Face this problem many time i solve in my way  like this and it is working

- First of all Close your eclipse .
- Then End Process of adb.exe from Task Manager.
- Then in command line go to your directory of platform-tools like

  `C:\AndroidSetup\sdk\platform-tools>`
- Then write following command step by step

  `C:\AndroidSetup\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server` 
  `C:\AndroidSetup\sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server`
- After successfully message come your adb is running now .
- Now you can start your eclispe your.
- Hope your adb is runnig now.

Comment: On the mac it's a little simpler. Just navigate to the `platform-tools` folder of your android SDK folder, and double click to open the adb file.

Answer (score 2):

Below steps worked for me.

1. Close the Eclipse if running
2. Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
3. Go to Tak manager and kill adb.exe
4. From command prompt type adb start-server

If No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.

Now you can start Eclipse again. Restart phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had face this problem and got solution too.
Follow these steps after close your  adt -

**1.Re install java** *I will suggest jxpiinstall to be install*

**2. Execute that file adb.exe**

**3. Set the envirnoment path again**

**4. And Here you can have your working adt**

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

> add the path to SDK tools and platform tools in your classpath from
>   Environment Variables. Then restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Kill `adb.exe` from task manager and restart Eclipse. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the above all suggested answer try this one also, it worked for me

copy the hprof-conv.exe from C:\adt\sdk\tools to C:\adt\sdk\platform-tools 
and 
copy the adb.exe from C:\adt\sdk\tools to C:\adt\sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved my issue. I go to Task Manager in `windows7 -> processes -> selected the adb.exe -> End Process`. After that I go to `cmd` prompt and type `adb start-server`. This time adb statred succefully. I run eclipe and it was showing no error.

Answer (score 0):

- Close your Eclipse
- Go to your adb.exe in my case it is located at
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
- click on adb.exe
- Start Eclipse and Happy Coding