# ECLIPSE-The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured

Tags: android, windows-7, adb

I've spent day trying to launch any Android program. it gives me the same error:

"The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured".

I'm running Eclipse Galileo,on a Windows7 machine.

I've used all the tricks I can find on the web: the command line "adb kill-server", the DDMS "reset ADB", I started the emulator both before and after Eclipse, and searched for ports being used by other programs.

when starting server getting same

```
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured

Comment: Are you sure you have admin rights?

Comment: yes @NishanthiGrashia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to end process of **adb.exe** from task manager ==> processes

then restart the eclipse

Comment: after you kill the server you should start it adb start-server

Comment: In cmd also getting same exception                                     * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *

Answer (score 1):

I've been encountering this error for how many times, and so I discovered some way of solving this. All I did is turn off my PC and also my phone (Pull out my phone battery and SD card). And first thing to do after turning on my PC go to CMD (Command Line) and type ..

adb devices
 .. and see if its working already you could see this.

- daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
- daemon started successfully *

Then you could run your Eclipse and try to run your Application.

*thats what i've been doing to solve that
*hope it help you too guys

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the eclipse edition and the emulator.
For immediate workaround,

1. try different edition of eclipse and import the same project.
2. try other emulators such as : https://www.manymo.com/

   http://www.genymotion.com/