# * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon *

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, ubuntu

I tried `./adb devices` from `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` directory  and I got  `* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon *`

I expected something like this:

```
List of devices attached
HT9CPP809576 device
```

If I try `./adb kill-server` and after that `./adb start-server` I get

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
```

If I try `./adb nodaemon server` I get `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

I have 32bit lubuntu 15.04. I use Android studio. My Android phone(LG l50) is plugged into the computer.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: try to remove .Android folder from Home firstly.

Comment: @Tronum why should i do that?

Comment: just save folder and try to ./adb kill-server - ./adb start-server

Comment: Problem can relates on cache.

Comment: @Tronum I restarted the computer and try with ./adb kill-server - ./adb start-server and I got the same error.

Comment: OK. Check this posts:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415746/how-to-resolve-the-adb-server-didnt-ack-error

Comment: this solved the problem for me: sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb

Comment: That's can be. You reinstall adb so cache was cleared. It's probably solve your issue. Anyway issue was solved? Close it.

Comment: @Tronum how do you know it was installed in the first place ?

Comment: you can try to use command "locate tools/hierarchyviewer" and check places with your sdk dirs. if it only one - all fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run `tasklist | findstr /i adb` to see if the **adb** is running. 
If it is still running, you can kill it with `taskkill /f /im adb.exe`.
Then restart the adb by `adb start-server`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it saved me from become mad !

Answer (score -1):

this error could be due to port 5037 is getting used by other process.
Try to set the adb server port to other, windows set ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT = XXXX

Comment: Could you please add more details to the solution you provide?