# adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (36); killing

Tags: android, react-native, adb, genymotion, create-react-native-app

I was trying to run react-native application (Created using create-react-native-app) on Genymotion in my Ubuntu PC.
When I run `npm run android` I'm getting this error,

```
could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

So I searched and followed [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415746/how-to-resolve-the-adb-server-didnt-ack-error) answer of this stackoverflow question. (When I first run `adb kill-server` it showed that `adb is not found` so I installed it using `sudo apt install adb` )
But when I run `adb start-server` (according to the answer) I'm getting this error now,

```
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Why is that ? What have I done wrong ?

Comment: The reason for this error was adb version in SDK was 1.0.39 and global adb version was 1.0.36 . So first I removed global adb using `sudo apt-get remove ` then I try to set global variable path to SDK version but didn't work. So according to an answer of [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8401) problem I copied the adb folder of sdk to /usr/local/bin and restarted the adb server and it worked

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I installed the android-tools-adb on my Linux Mint / Ubuntu for some reason and got into this situation. removing got it working back again.