# Genymotion Android 5.0 Lollipop adb not connecting with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, genymotion

With Genymotion latest update, able to boot the Android 5.0 lollipop image but not able to connect to it from Eclipse. Not able to launch app into it.

Following is the output seen in the Console WIndow of eclipse:

```
[2014-11-23 02:43:13 - MyApp] ------------------------------
[2014-11-23 02:43:13 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2014-11-23 02:43:13 - MyApp] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-11-23 02:43:13 - MyApp] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-11-23 02:43:13 - MyApp] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at   'C:\Users\homepc\Documents\code\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Anyone encoutered this problem and know a way to get around this? My setup is working perfectly fine when I have another Genymotion image running - like Android version 4.3 or 4.4.

**INVESTIGATING ISSUE WITH MY SETUP - OLDER OS VERSIONS not working**

Comment: Try to restart adb.exe from task manager.

Comment: Are you using ADB included with Genymotion or your own?

Comment: using genymotion, installed the plugin in eclipse. looks like i need to get back to a working condition with 4.3 and 4.4 versions first - i will get back on this thread if i still need help.

Comment: My issue is resolved, sorry for the false alarm here. I had to close adb.exe from the task manager in addition to 'adb kill-server' and then 'adb start-server' (this thread helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304324/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured-you-must-restart-a)